# React passes wrong parameter along function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a for loop to create some svg paths but have some trouble passing a parameter alongside the function. Everything added with the props uses the correct i value, except selectRegion(i). This gets 2 as value, which I think is the final value of i after finishing the loop. How do I pass the correct i value?

```
    componentDidMount() {
        var regions = []
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.regionNames.length; i++) {
            var region = <Region id={i} border={this.state.regionBorders[i]} color={this.state.regionColors[i]} selectRegion={() => this.selectRegion(i)}/>;
            regions.push(region);
        }
        this.setState({regions: regions});
    }

    // Select region.
    selectRegion(id) {
        alert(id);
        this.setState({selRegion: id});
    }
```

Region component

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    
    export default class Region extends Component {
        
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: props.id,
            color: props.color,
            border: props.border,
            opacity: "0.3",
            is_selected: false
        }
    }

    mouseEnter = (is_enter) => {
        if(is_enter) {
            this.setState({opacity: "0.5"});
            alert(this.state.id);
            this.props.selectRegion();
        } else if (!this.state.is_selected) {
            this.setState({opacity: "0.3"});
        }
    }

    mouseClick = () => {
        this.setState({is_selected: !this.state.is_selected})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <path d={this.state.border}
                  fill={this.state.color}
                  fill-opacity={this.state.opacity}
                  onClick={() => this.mouseClick()}
                  onMouseEnter={() => this.mouseEnter(true)} 
                  onMouseLeave={() => this.mouseEnter(false)}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you have to change the loop variable i from a var to a let, that is `for (let i; ...)`

Comment: you didn't post the Region component

Comment: @yochanansheinberger I only included part of it, I've updated the post to include everything.

Answer (score 0):

@Norse was correct I've fixed it by doing the following:

```
// Generate map regions.
    componentDidMount() {
        var regions = []
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.regionNames.length; i++) {
            var region = <Region id={i} border={this.state.regionBorders[i]} color={this.state.regionColors[i]} selectRegion={() => this.selectRegion(i)}/>;
            regions.push(region);
        }
        this.setState({regions: regions});
    }
```